# Terraform code to create a new user and login on Azure SQL database with Database owner permissions

Tags: azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform code that deploys Azure SQL database with server admin credentials. But I would like to create a separate user and login on the Database with dbo permissions. Could someone please help with terraform code for this?

Comment: Can this blog be helfull https://serverfault.com/questions/930091/how-to-create-database-user-and-assign-role-to-it-with-terraform?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reference this blog: [How to create database user and assign role to it with terraform](https://serverfault.com/questions/930091/how-to-create-database-user-and-assign-role-to-it-with-terraform):

I've started working on a Terraform provider that will do this over at https://github.com/jayway/terraform-provider-mssql. It's still very early work, but I've managed to make it provision logins and users for those logins in a local SQL Server instance (that was already running, so I haven't tested it at all in conjunction with e.g. the AzureRM provider). Testing and contributions are very welcome (but don't use it for production scenarios just yet)!

User sumit salunke accepted(marked) it as answer, I think it should works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, i see that code is for psql. I am looking for Azure SQL Database. @sumit salunke do you have the code for Azure SQL

Comment: @DevOpslearner I think you should try yourself by change connection string to Azure SQL.